# How to create one folder at Google Drive for new folder creation and ID number of new folder

Tags: ios

How to create one folder at Google Drive after our device obtains the authorization of “GTMAppAuth”? Is the SDK inclusive of the API for new folder creation and ID number of new folder? If yes, how to get the API ad ID number.